# Format Intl.DateTimeFormat Locale options

Tags: time

After some help here, some online reading, and some headaches, we have managed to get the current time of Rome and updated constantly as if it was in real-time.
Now I am trying to format the way date/time are displayed, but I cannot modify some parameters.

Here is my code:

```
let timer = setInterval(updateTime, 0);

function updateTime() {
    const localeOptions = {
        timeZone: 'Europe/Rome',
        dateStyle: 'full',
        timeStyle: 'short',
        formatMatcher: 'day, month, year',
        year: '2-digit'
    };
    const timetag = document.getElementById('timetag');
    const url = "https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Rome"
    fetch(url).then(r => r.json()).then(r => {
        const d = new Date(r.datetime);
        timetag.innerText = d.toLocaleString('it-IT', localeOptions)
    });
}
```

Everything works until I insert the formatMatcher and the year in 2-digits. I'm following the parameters from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) so I wonder what is making everything breaking?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/qvyt02u3/) the JSFiddle of the timer.

My goal is to have something like 16 APR | 14:06, or at least the closer possible to something minimal in its details and space being taken on screen.

What's wrong in the code, especially in the formatMatcher and year? They break everything ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Can you imagine any problems happening from `fetch` every 0 milliseconds?

You essentially have the solution, the parts just need to be assembled differently.

The `localeOptions` is misconfigured -

```
RangeError: formatMatcher must be either "basic" or "best fit"

TypeError: dateStyle and timeStyle may not be used with other DateTimeFormat options
```

Fixing that, we have a basic demo -

```js
const f = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("it-IT", {
  timeZone: 'Europe/Rome',
  dateStyle: 'full',
  timeStyle: 'short',
})

console.log(f.format(new Date()))
// lunedì 17 ottobre 2022, 18:08
```

Parts like `fetch` are not needed, helping us avoid costly network requests.

Now we can write the `setInterval` code -

```js
const dtf = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("it-IT", {
  timeZone: 'Europe/Rome',
  dateStyle: 'full',
  timeStyle: 'long',
})

setInterval(() => {
  document.body.textContent = dtf.format(new Date())
}, 0)
```

But `setInterval` has issues when used in this way. A better option is [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) -

```js
const dtf = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("it-IT", {
  timeZone: 'Europe/Rome',
  dateStyle: 'full',
  timeStyle: 'long',
})

requestAnimationFrame(function update(frame) {
  document.body.textContent = dtf.format(new Date())
  requestAnimationFrame(update)
})
```